# how can I connect the same speakers to two different computers?

Tags: speakers

I have two computers, and I want to connect the same set of speakers to both of them. Is that even possible?

I hope this is appropriate for superuser, I see most questions here are software questions.

Comment: Do you want to hear sound from the two computers simultaneously? Or switch between them?

Comment: prefer the first option, but if it is not possible, the second option is reasonable as well.

Comment: using simple Y adaption for analog to feed 2 line-level signals into the same powered or unpowered speakers is usually possible and workable.  If there were noises from cross interferance, a ground loop isolator (1:1 transformer) could be used in those situations, on one of the lines. When you get into 5.1 and 7.1 analog the connections might get more difficult but it would still be possible.  Using the Data lines optical and spdif stuff would present more difficulties.  One analog and one digital connection, would be dependant on the speaker system, and i would say most would not.

Answer (score 4):

Get one of these [TinyMix](http://www.stoweblank.com/tinymix) device -

[image]